Add packaging slip to mail in Woocommerce mail
I want to add a packaging slip to an automatic email.
This seems to work well when i trigger the mail on an order status change for example.
when i trigger the mail on a "status = processing", the packaging slip isn't attached.
I think this is caused by the fact that the document isn't created yet.
When i execute the code after the document is created, everyting works fine.
this is the current code:
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'protempo_maybe_send_order_mail', 2000, 1);

function protempo_maybe_send_order_mail( $order_id ) {


    $logger  = wc_get_logger();
    $context = array( 'source' => 'protempo' );
 
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    
    foreach ( $order->get_shipping_methods() as $shipping_methods ) {
      $shipping_method_id = $shipping_methods->get_method_id();
    }
    
    if ( 'local_pickup' == $shipping_method_id ) {
        $logger->debug( 'Not sent for order #' . $order->get_id() . ', reason: shipping is local pickup.', $context );
        return; // Don't send the email for local pickup ;
        
    }


    if ( in_array( $order->get_status(), array( 'cancelled', 'failed' ) ) ) {

        $logger->debug( 'Not sent for order #' . $order->get_id() . ', reason: failed or cancelled.', $context );
        return; // Don't send the email for failed or cancelled orders;

    }

    $order_meta = get_post_meta( $order_id );

    
    $protempo_products = array();
    $leveranciers_products = array();

    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {

        $product_id = $item->get_product()->get_id();

        // Only products wiht artikelnummer.
        if ( get_post_meta( $product_id, '_protempoartikelnummer', true ) ) {

          $protempo_products[] = array(
              'code' => get_post_meta( $product_id, '_protempoartikelnummer', true ),
              'qty'  => $item->get_quantity()
          );

        } else {

            // Only products wiht leveranciers_id.
            if ( get_post_meta( $product_id, '_leveranciers_id', true ) ) {

              $leveranciers_products[] = array(
                  'code' => get_post_meta( $product_id, '_leveranciers_id', true ),
                  'qty'  => $item->get_quantity()
              );

            }
        }
    }

    if ( 0 == count( $protempo_products ) &&  0 == count( $leveranciers_products ) ) {

        $logger->debug( 'Not sent for order #' . $order->get_id() . ', reason: no protempo/leveranciers products found.', $context );
        return; // No protempo/leveranciers products to be emailed.

    }
      
      $bedrijfsnaam = $order_meta['_shipping_company'][0];

      if ( $bedrijfsnaam == '' ) {
        $bedrijfsnaam = $order_meta['_shipping_first_name'][0] . ' ' . $order_meta['_shipping_last_name'][0] . ' (particulier)';
      }

      $straat   = $order_meta['_shipping_address_1'][0];
      $huisnr   = $order_meta['_shipping_address_2'][0];
      $postcode = $order_meta['_shipping_postcode'][0];
      $plaats   = $order_meta['_shipping_city'][0];
      $land     = $order_meta['_shipping_country'][0];
      $telefoon = $order_meta['_shipping_phone'][0];
      $referentie_klant = $order->get_order_number();
      $pakbon_url = 'https://woocommerce-915068-4990040.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/wpo_wcpdf_26c85ba985c77a4a0b8c72f6abcfac50/archive/';
      $pakbon = $order_meta['_wpo_wcpdf_packing_slip_archived'][0];  
    

      $mail_klant = $order_meta['_billing_email'][0];

    

    $referentieklant = utf8_encode( $order_meta['_billing_reference'][0] );
    $opmerkingen     = utf8_encode( $order->get_customer_note() );
    
    if ( count( $protempo_products ) ) { 
        
        $destination = 'protempo';
    
         // Protempo order
        $body = '{"order": {';
        $body.= '"debiteurennummer": "52866",';
        $body.= '"aflever_straat": '       . json_encode( $straat ) . ',';
        $body.= '"email_klant": '       . json_encode( $mail_klant ) . ',';
        $body.= '"aflever_bedrijfsnaam": ' . json_encode( $bedrijfsnaam ) . ',';
        $body.= '"aflever_straat": '       . json_encode( $straat ) . ',';
        $body.= '"aflever_huisnr": '       . json_encode( $huisnr ) . ',';
        $body.= '"aflever_postcode": '     . json_encode( $postcode ) . ',';
        $body.= '"aflever_plaats": '       . json_encode( $plaats ) . ',';
        $body.= '"aflever_land": '         . json_encode( $land ) . ',';
        $body.= '"aflever_telefoon": '     . json_encode( $telefoon ) . ',';
        $body.= '"referentie_klant": "HELPO #' . $referentie_klant . '",';
        $body.= '"opmerkingen": '          . json_encode( $opmerkingen ) . ',';
        $body.= '"products": {"product":'  . json_encode( $protempo_products ) . '}';
        $body.= '}}';


        $body.= "<br/><br/>je kan de pakbon downoaden via: " .$pakbon_url.$pakbon;

        $attachments = array(WP_CONTENT_DIR."/uploads/wpo_wcpdf_26c85ba985c77a4a0b8c72f6abcfac50/archive/". $pakbon);


        $multiple_recipients = array (
                                    'xxx@mail.com',
                                    'xxx@mail.com',
                                );
        
    } else {

        $destination = 'Leveranciers';
            
        // Leveranciers order
        $body = '{"order": {';
        $body.= '"debiteurennummer": "xxxx",';
        $body.= '"aflever_bedrijfsnaam": ' . json_encode( $bedrijfsnaam ) . ',';
        $body.= '"aflever_straat": '       . json_encode( $straat ) . ',';
        $body.= '"email_klant": '       . json_encode( $mail_klant ) . ',';
        $body.= '"aflever_huisnr": '       . json_encode( $huisnr ) . ',';
        $body.= '"aflever_postcode": '     . json_encode( $postcode ) . ',';
        $body.= '"aflever_plaats": '       . json_encode( $plaats ) . ',';
        $body.= '"aflever_land": '         . json_encode( $land ) . ',';
        $body.= '"aflever_telefoon": '     . json_encode( $telefoon ) . ',';
        $body.= '"referentie_klant": "HELPO #' . $referentie_klant . '",';
        $body.= '"opmerkingen": '          . json_encode( $opmerkingen ) . ',';
        $body.= '"products": {"product":'  . json_encode( $leveranciers_products ) . '}';
        $body.= '}}';



        $multiple_recipients = array (
                                    //'xxx@mail.com',
                                    'xxx@mail.com',
                                    'xxx@mail.com',
                                );
    }

    $subject   = 'Helpo webshop orderid: ' .  $referentie_klant;
    $headers[] = 'From: Helpo <xxx@mail.com>';
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';

    

    
    // wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers ); //
    if ( wp_mail( $multiple_recipients, $subject, $body, $headers, $attachments ) ) {

        $logger->debug( 'Sent for order #' . $order->get_id() . ' ' . $destination, $context );

        // Record we have sent the email to prevent sending it again.

        $order->update_meta_data( 'protempo_sent_email', 'Yes' );
        $order->save();

    } else {

        $logger->debug( 'Failure to send email for order #' . $order->get_id(), $context );

    }
}

i tried adding a "waiting mechanism". but this doesn't seem to resolve the issue.
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'protempo_maybe_send_order_mail', 2000, 1);

function protempo_maybe_send_order_mail($order_id) {
    $logger  = wc_get_logger();
    $context = array('source' => 'protempo');

    // Haal de bestelling op
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

    // Controleer of de bestelling bestaat
    if (!$order) {
        $logger->debug('Order not found for ID: ' . $order_id, $context);
        return;
    }

    // Verzendmail niet voor lokale afhaling
    foreach ($order->get_shipping_methods() as $shipping_methods) {
        $shipping_method_id = $shipping_methods->get_method_id();
    }

    if ('local_pickup' == $shipping_method_id) {
        $logger->debug('Not sent for order #' . $order->get_id() . ', reason: shipping is local pickup.', $context);
        return;
    }

    // Controleer of de bestelling is geannuleerd of mislukt
    if (in_array($order->get_status(), array('cancelled', 'failed'))) {
        $logger->debug('Not sent for order #' . $order->get_id() . ', reason: failed or cancelled.', $context);
        return;
    }

    $order_meta = get_post_meta($order_id);
    $pakbon = $order_meta['_wpo_wcpdf_packing_slip_archived'][0];
    $pakbon_url = 'https://woocommerce-915068-4990040.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/wpo_wcpdf_26c85ba985c77a4a0b8c72f6abcfac50/archive/';

    // Wacht tot de bijlage beschikbaar is
    $timeout = 120; // Maximum wachttijd in seconden
    $wait_time = 5; // Hoeveel tijd er tussen elke check moet zitten
    $elapsed_time = 0;

    while (!file_exists(WP_CONTENT_DIR . "/uploads/wpo_wcpdf_26c85ba985c77a4a0b8c72f6abcfac50/archive/" . $pakbon) && $elapsed_time < $timeout) {
        sleep($wait_time);
        $elapsed_time += $wait_time;
    }

    // Controleer nogmaals of de bijlage bestaat
    if (!file_exists(WP_CONTENT_DIR . "/uploads/wpo_wcpdf_26c85ba985c77a4a0b8c72f6abcfac50/archive/" . $pakbon)) {
        $logger->debug('Not sent for order #' . $order->get_id() . ', reason: packing slip not available after waiting.', $context);
        return;
    }

    // De rest van je logica om de e-mail te verzenden
    // ...

    // Bij voorbeeld: $attachments = array(...); hier na de controle

    if (wp_mail($multiple_recipients, $subject, $body, $headers, $attachments)) {
        $logger->debug('Sent for order #' . $order->get_id() . ' ' . $destination, $context);
        $order->update_meta_data('protempo_sent_email', 'Yes');
        $order->save();
    } else {
        $logger->debug('Failure to send email for order #' . $order->get_id(), $context);
    }
}



The delay mechanism might not be enough if the packing slip creation process is delayed by other tasks.
Instead of waiting manually, trigger your email after the packing slip is actually generated.
Use a hook to your plugin:
add_action('wpo_wcpdf_document_created', 'protempo_send_email_with_packing_slip', 10, 2);

function protempo_send_email_with_packing_slip($document, $order) {
    if ($document->get_type() == 'packing-slip') {
        // Get the order ID and pass it to your email function
        $order_id = $order->get_id();
        protempo_maybe_send_order_mail($order_id);
    }
}

EDIT:
Try using the wp_schedule_single_event in your current code as a new solution for a waiting mechanism.
// Schedule the email with a delay
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'protempo_schedule_delayed_email', 20, 1);

function protempo_schedule_delayed_email($order_id) {
    // Schedule the email function to run after a delay (e.g., 10 seconds)
    if (!wp_next_scheduled('protempo_send_delayed_email', array($order_id))) {
        wp_schedule_single_event(time() + 10, 'protempo_send_delayed_email', array($order_id));
    }
}

// Hook the delayed function to send the email with the packing slip
add_action('protempo_send_delayed_email', 'protempo_maybe_send_order_mail', 10, 1);


looks like the action doesn't get triggered. I was doing some research but i can't find any documentation regarding: wpo_wcpdf_document_created

Edited my answer above with another suggestion
